# Why when I create a spring boot kotlin project I am forced to make all classes open?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

Why when I create a spring boot kotlin project I am forced to make all classes open?
This is really difficult for me to understand! Is this a new characteristic of the language? Or is it something I am doing? All I do is creating a simple spring boot project with no dependencies, and on Java 8

Comment: Kotlin classes are final by default, some Spring functionality requires classes to be open, so that they are extendable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using maven, you can add dependency `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-allopen` to `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin` so that you cont need to `open` classes which require spring to create proxied instances (like @Configuration annotated, aspects, etc...)

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                    <jvmTarget>${java.version}</jvmTarget>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

#### Edit:

Also, I know question is not asking it but if you plan to use `mockito` you'll face same issue when trying to mock non-open classes. That issue can be fixed by adding file named `org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` in test resources in directory `mockito-extensions` with a content

`src/test/resources/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker`:

```
mock-maker-inline
```

#### Edit 2

As for explicit answer *Why classes need to be open?*:
It is because when spring processes beans in some situations like creating @Configuration class bean, it will create CGLIB proxy, and creation of such proxy is actually defining new class at runtime which extends your class being proxied.

One of reasons why those proxies are created for @Configuirationn annotated classes is to support caching of @Bean annotated factory methods to avoid duplicated creation of singleton-scoped beans.

Take look at following example:

```
@Configuration
class MyConfig {

  @Bean
  fun foo(): Foo {
     log.info("Creating bean Foo")
     return Foo()
  }

  
  @Bean
  fun bar(): Foo {
     log.info("Creating bean Bar")
     val foo = foo()
     return Bar(foo)
  }

  @Bean
  fun baz(): Baz {
     log.info("Creating bean Baz")
     val foo = foo()
     return Baz(foo)
  }


}
```

Here we have 3 beans. foo, bar and baz. Look how methods `bar()` and `baz()` invoke `foo()`

If your application needs those 3 beans, by looking at this code you would expect that `Creating bean Foo` will be logged 3 times, once when creating
bean `foo`, once when creating bean `bar` and once when creating bean `baz`.

But, what will actually happen is that bean `foo` will be created only once, and each following invocation of factory method `foo()` will simply return cached bean. That's why proxy for class `MyConfig` is created hence need for class to be non-final i.e. open.

Comment: the question is `Why` the classes need to be open, not What library can be used to automagically make them open so that I don't have to type it. Also this is kind of wrong `so that you don't need to open classes`, true you don't have to type it, but that is because your classes are now open by default.

Comment: @Alex.T I've edited an answer with more detailed explanation _why_ some classes need to be extended by proxies and one of reasons for proxy in the first place. Hoping it's more useful